# How to copy left navigation from sharepoint 2013 to sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, sharepoint-server, left-navigation

I am moving the site from on-prime to online. I want to copy the navigation from 2013 to online for the same site using pnp powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample script for the **top-level sites**:

```
#Parameters for sites
$SourceSub = "http://<spserver>/sites/site1"
$TargetSub = "https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/site2"

#Connect to SP site using PnP PowerShell
$Username1 = "<Admin>"
$Password1 = "<Password>"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName1, $(convertto-securestring $Password1 -asplaintext -force)
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SourceSub -Credential $cred

#Get Navigation Links from SP
$n = Get-PnPNavigationNode -Location QuickLaunch

#Connect to SPO site using PnP PowerShell
$Username2 = "<Admin>"
$Password2 = "<Password>"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName2, $(convertto-securestring $Password2 -asplaintext -force)
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $TargetSub -Credential $cred

#Add Navigation Links to SPO
Foreach($_ in $n){
    Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title $_.Title -Url $_.Url -Location QuickLaunch
}
```

Remember to update the credentials for both environments.

Please note that it only gets the **top-level nodes** in the Quick Launch.

References: [Get-PnPNavigationNode.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpnavigationnode?view=sharepoint-ps) / [Add-PnPNavigationNode.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpnavigationnode?view=sharepoint-ps)